# Nested object array update mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a value in the nested array but can't get it to work.

My object is like this

```
                    User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id : userId, 'vehicle._id' : vehicleId },{ $push : { reg_number : reg_number,
                  category : category, model_year: model_year, insurance_date:insurance_date, tax_date:tax_date,
                  vehicle_name:vehicle_name }}, function(err, vehicle){

                if(err) { throw err }
                req.flash('success','Updated');

                //res.render('dashboard/vehicleUpdate', {vehicle});
              });
```

Mongodb looks like the following:

[image: DB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, also check [Update Values in an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays)

```
User.updateOne({ _id : userId, "vehicle._id" : vehicleId },
{ $set: { "vehicle.$.reg_number" : reg_number }}, function(err, vehicle)
{
       if(err) { throw err }
                req.flash('success','Updated');

            //res.render('dashboard/vehicleUpdate', {vehicle});
              });
```